# Extending JBoss AS 7 logging to database

Tags: jboss7.x, slf4j

We have jboss logging enabled in our application. Currently we are using the 'Rotating-file-handler' to log everything to files. This is defined in the jboss 'standalone.xml' file. We are looking into logging some of the information into a logging database as well; for the sake of building indicators etc.

Can someone offer some options that we can utilize here. Our end goal is that as things are being written to the file; we would intercept and write it to DB. We dont want to do that in-line since that would be a blocking call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link shows EXACTLY how to set up what i wanted. JBoss AS 7.0.1 has a feature to support custom log handlers.

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/CustomLogHandlersOn701